# AWS CDK how to remove "role" prefix in ARN

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

AWS CDK is adding ROLE prefix in the ARN , is there a way to remove that .. Below is the CDK code

arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:**role**/edo-dps-deng-iam-crossaccount-sqs-access-dev

```
sf_iam_role = _iam.Role(
    scope=self,
    id=f"edo-dps-deng-iam-crossaccount-sqs-access-{deploy_env}-id",
    assumed_by=_iam.CompositePrincipal(
        _iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
        _iam.ServicePrincipal("firehose.amazonaws.com"),
        _iam.ServicePrincipal("sqs.amazonaws.com"),
    ),
    role_name=f"edo-dps-deng-iam-crossaccount-sqs-access-{deploy_env}",
    path=None,
    inline_policies={
        f"edo-dps-deng-{deploy_env}-sofa-iam-role-policy": _iam.PolicyDocument.from_json(
            json_data
        )
    },
)
```

Comment: By default, AWS CDK adds the ROLE prefix to the IAM role name in the ARN. IAM roles are a distinct type of AWS resource, and ROLE prefix helps to differentiate.

Alternative is Fn::Join function in your CDK code to concatenate the AWS account ID and the role name into a custom ARN string without the ROLE prefix.

Comment: ```custom_arn = Fn.join(':', ['arn', 'aws', 'iam', Fn.ref('AWS::AccountId'), sf_iam_role.role_name])```

Comment: @Yash where is the option to specify CUSTOM_ARN when creating the ROLE https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/Role.html 
Thanks

Comment: It's not there, as that is impossible. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to remove, as that is the required syntax for IAM Role ARNs. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-arns).

`arn:aws:iam::account:role/role-name-with-path`